# How to Sketch a graph of a extended function from one intervel to another intervel

Tags: fourier-series

I have already done part a,b,c. But in d part they ask to extend the function. I can't understand how to extend it and sketch the extended function.
[image]

Comment: What has this to do with ODE? A periodic continuation looks like a periodic function.

Comment: Part b says $f(x)$ is periodic with period $2\pi$. You know what the function looks like from $-\pi$ to $\pi$. That tells you what the function looks like everywhere.